# Objective-C, Spritekit error "Texture Atlas 'customer_1_3' cannot be found."

Tags: objective-c, texture-atlas

I have the exact folder "customer_1_3.atlas" placed in the project. I drag and drop it into the project and I check "Copy if needed" when i do that. Still, I am getting this message and the program breaks. Where can the problem be guys? I attached the image with the correctly positioned atlas folder and the error that occurs and - apparently - crashes the app.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like so:
1. Making a backup copy of the atlas on the desktop (name the folder with .atlas extension).
3. Delete the atlas from XCode, via XCode (select move to Trash when deleting).
3. Right click in the project, select add files to project "APP NAME".
4. Select those same backup atlases and thus import them.
5. Problem solved, the atlases work fine.